# VB.net change text in button control with variable

Tags: vb.net

How can I change a specific control, with variable .text

```
If Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button) = ("Button" & Bindex) Then
  button.Text = PostMyresult
End If
```

So , no Joy, attached is the code block. Hope its not too polluted:

` Private Sub Button34_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button34.Click

```
    Dim DaButton As String
    For Bindex As Integer = 1 To 2

        DaButton = ("Button" & Bindex & ".Text = SAMPLE" & Bindex)
        MessageBox.Show(DaButton)
        ' Me.Button1.Text = "SAMPLE1"
        CollectSample(DaButton & ".Text" & ".txt")  'works grabs sample from spectrum anlzr
        CheckSample(DaButton & ".Text" & ".txt")    'works error check

        ' MessageBox.Show(SampleFlag)
        If SampleFlag <> 0 Then
            SendMyAvg = Math.Round(SendMyAvg, 2)
            If SendMyAvg < 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Average Sample Is < 1 ")
                ' Me.Button1.Text = "SAMPLE1"
                For Each myCtrl As Control In Me.Controls
                    If (TypeOf myCtrl Is Button) Then
                        If myCtrl.Name = "Button" & Bindex Then
                            myCtrl.Text = DaButton
                        End If
                    End If
                Next

                Exit Sub
            End If
            '  MessageBox.Show("Button" & Bindex & " / " & SendMyAvg)

            For Each myCtrl As Control In Me.Controls
                If (TypeOf myCtrl Is Label) & myCtrl.Name = "Label" & Bindex Then
                    myCtrl.Text = SendMyAvg
                    MessageBox.Show("Button" & Bindex & " / " & SendMyAvg)
                End If
            Next
            '   Button1.Text = SendMyAvg
            '  MsgBox("Avg Is " & SendMyAvg)
        End If
    Next
End Sub`
```

Comment: `Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)` will be a subset of the controls which are buttons.  You need to iterate and find the one you want

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have Linq, you can do this:

```
    Dim btn = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button).Where(Function(x) x.Name = "Button1" & Bindex)
    If btn.Count > 0 Then
        btn(0).Text = "New Text"
    End If
```

Comment: To the person who gave a negative. Why?

Comment: Not my negative, but it may be because you are selecting the button whose **Text** property is `"Button1" + Bindex` when the question is probably asking about the button whose **Name** property is `"Button1" & Bindex` (and note that it is better to use the string concatenation operator - & in VB).

Comment: Oh. Well I don't think that's really worth the negative there but thanks for that. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  For Each myBtn as Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
       If myBtn.Name = "Button" & Bindex Then
            myBtn.Text = PostMyResult
       End If
  Next
```

Comment: that will change *every* button not just the one s/he is looking for

Comment: if you use `For Each btn As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)` sort of like the OP has, you can get rid of the first If block.  Then check it under Option Strict

Comment: Thanks for the additional knowledge! Answer edited. You're right. It will also lessen the controls it has to iterate. Thanks again.

Comment: I would suggest adding a `.Where(...)` clause rather than using an `If`.

Comment: No joy, as this is my first VB project, probably missing something.

Answer (score 1):

solution:

DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("Label" & Bindex, True)(0), Label).Text = SendMyAvg

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim c As Control
    Dim myButton As String

    For i = 1 To 2
        myButton = "Button" & i
        c = Controls.Find(myButton, True).FirstOrDefault()
        c.Text = "New Text"
    Next i
```